# Как в Django создать страницу, доступную только авторизованным пользователям?

Tags: python, django

подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть простенький шаблон в django

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('custom_page/save_data_doc.html', custom_page.views.show_admin_custom_page),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Хотелось бы что бы эта страничка была доступна только авторизованным пользователям, или только Администратору, как такое можно реализовать в django?

Answer (score 1):

Моя задача решилась следующим образом. Мне в целом надо было запретить доступ к странице извне, и решилось это достаточно просто (хотя потратил много времени на поиск информации)
во views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required
def show_admin_custom_page(request):
    return render(request,'custom_page/save_data_doc.html')
```

Теперь если я вышел из админки, выбрасывается 404, если авторизован, то все ок статус 200, надеюсь кому то поможет